# How should I use automation with OpenOffice to convert HTML files to RTF?

Tags: ole, openoffice.org

I would like to convert HTML to RTF and vice-versa and would like to use OpenOffice converters. Is it possible (with or without automation)?

Answer (score -3):

So you are trying to convert. This process usually works.

1. Open up the html file in Notepad.
2. Click File.
3. Click Save As.
4. Now change the file extension to .rtf and make sure the extension is under All Files.

Did it work?

Comment: I mean, convert files programatically with or without OLE automation.